# Azure Service Bus with nodejs: get messages from queue extremely slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, azureservicebus

This is callback for handling incoming messges from queue:

```
function startListen(){
    serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage(queueForRequest, {isPeekLock:true},
    function(error, lockedMessage) { handleMessage(error, lockedMessage)} );
}

function handleMessage(err, msg){
    if(typeof msg !== "undefined"){ //if msg has been received, delete it
    serviceBusService.deleteMessage(msg, function(deleteError){
        if(deleteError) console.log('Can not delete message');
    });  
  } 

    if (!err){
    var result = ProcessMessage(msg);
    sendResponse(result);
    }
    else{console.log(err);}

    startListen(); //try get message again
}
```

Such code works bad. Sometimes the server can get messages from queue, however very often `HandleMessage()` has err as argument:

> No message to receive

Finally some messages stays unprocessed. It works good at the start of listening therefore I think the issue hides in my code. What's wrong?

Comment: how did you end solving this problem? I would like to keep my client connected to the queue receiving messages whenever they are available.

Comment: @vilelam https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751434/5006880

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of the problem here and the library that you're using. However, I'd recommend using the latest libraries that are based on AMQP that are more reliable and you wouldn't see such an issue.

I know this is a late reply, but just in case someone is running into issues and landed here, refer to the links below.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus`(based on AMQP) has been published.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)